# Unsure of how to proceed with functions related to istream and ostream

Tags: c++

I have to write a program that uses the following functions, but I'm not sure how to proceed from this point forward. Essentially, I want getValue to use the inputstream and outputstream referenced in the main function (cin and cout, in this case) but I get numerous errors. If needed, I can provide my header file.

```
#include "lab6.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream> 
using namespace std;

double getValue(istream inputStream, ostream outputStream, string promptUser) {
    double number;
    outputStream << promptUser;
    inputStream >> number;
    return number;
}


void convertRectToPolar(istream& inputStream, ostream& outputStream) {
    double x, y;
    string promptUser;
    promptUser = "Input the x value: ";
    x = getValue(inputStream, outputStream, promptUser);
    outputStream << "Input the y value: ";
    y = getValue(inputStream, outputStream, promptUser);
    if (inputStream.fail()) {
        outputStream << "Error: inputStream has failed.";
    }
}

int main() {

    convertRectToPolar(cin, cout);

}
```

Comment: `istream inputStream` and `ostream outputStream` won't work. Streams are not copyable. Make those references too.

Comment: You did it correctly in `convertRectToPolar`, just do the same in `getValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`istream inputStream` and `ostream outputStream` won't work. Streams are not copyable. Make those references too.

```
double getValue(istream& inputStream, ostream& outputStream, string promptUser) {
    double number;
    outputStream << promptUser;
    inputStream >> number;
    return number;
}
```

As a sidenote: You don't need to assign your prompt strings to a variable before you call `getValue`. Just put the prompt in the call and it'll be converted to a `std::string`:

```
void convertRectToPolar(istream& inputStream, ostream& outputStream) {
    double x = getValue(inputStream, outputStream, "Input the x value: ");
    double y = getValue(inputStream, outputStream, "Input the y value: ");

    if (inputStream.fail()) {
        outputStream << "Error: inputStream has failed.";
    }
}
```